# Error when wanting to push array into specific part of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I've been trying to push an array into another array in my local database. The first layer of arrays are different tests into which i push arrays of testresaults into which i want to push an array of comments using the following code:

```
    if (Array.isArray(newTest1)) {
        user.test1[1].push(newTest1);
      }
```

If I change it so it pushes the array into test1 then it works, like this:

```
if (Array.isArray(newTest1)) {
            user.test1.push(newTest1);
          }
```

How come the first piece of code does not work?

Comment: Where did you define `user.test1`? Sounds like `user.test1[1]` isn't an array.

Comment: What errors do you get from console? What kind of data structure is `test1`?

Comment: If you want to add an array to a specific place in the array you need to use `splice`.

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just doesn't add the array in the db.

Comment: i defined user in user.js as:
  test1: { type: Array, required: false },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.test1[1]` is most likely not an array.

`user.test1.splice(1, 0, newTest1)` should work for you.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: That works! But it merges the two arrays, anyway to do it so they don't merge?

Comment: @Oscar can you provide the output of `console.log(user.test1)`? Also, what do you mean by merging the arrays? You are modifying `user.test1` using push as well. If you want a separate copy of user.test1, you can use `slice` and `concat`.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this. But i can not console.log from my api.js file for some reason so i'm doing it from my management.js file instead which gives:

(5) [Array(4), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]

Comment: Okay. Technically the first code you have in the question is working fine pushing the `newTest1` array in `user.test1[1]`, however, since you mentioned Databases in the question, is it possible that the schema of `user.test1[1]` different from `newTest`? I am not sure why else it wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't think so. Yea it's really weird why this works: 
user.test1.splice(index, 0, newTest1)
and this doesn't...
user.test1[1].push(newTest1);
Could there be any other explanation for that?